# .htaccess rewrite rule not behaving as expected

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am attempting to have `http://mysite.com/orders/10000111` rewritten to `http://mysite.com/orders/details.pl/10000111`

Here is what I have in my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} ^orders\/([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^orders\/([0-9]+)$ orders/details.pl/$1 [NS,NC,QSA]
```

Can someone help out and tell me how I am being an idiot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need to escape `/` as in `\/`

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^orders/([0-9]+)$ /orders/details.pl/$1 [NC]
```

should do the job